# Add an object from UITextField to an NSMutableArray by clicking a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, xcode4.2

I need to add contents of textfield named `productName` to an `NSMutableArray` named `cartArray` by clicking on a button.

In the button action event I wrote:

```
NSString *productName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", productName.text];
cartArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[cartArray addObject:productName];

NSLog(@"Cart Array==%@", cartArray);
```

But i need to add that content of textfield each time user click on button. Here in console previous content in array not showing i.e. it's not get added each time.

Suggest me anything I need to do in `viewDidLoad` or anywhere else?

Comment: If I were you, I'd rethink whose answer to accept. The currently accepted answer is shit compared to some other answers, even if correct.

Comment: @ExplodingRat yes i have made it correct, that time i was new to iOS so ... any way thanks for review..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-creating the cartArray each time the button is pressed, thus overwriting the previous entry. Move the initialisation of the array to viewDidLoad or your init method.

Also productName.text is already a string, there is no need to do the stringWithFormat.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewDidLoad:animated];
        cartArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}


- (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender {
        [cartArray addObject:productName.text];
        NSLog(@"Cart Array==%@",cartArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because everytime it is initializing your array:

```
cartArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You should not initialize it every time, initialize it once in `viewDidLoad` and then add object in button action.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the array in `viewdidload`

```
cartArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and remove the array from action event call function.

Comment: Thank you SenthilKumar once again you helped me exactly.